# gulp - compiling Vue component without `require`

Tags: javascript, gulp, vue.js

I'm trying to understand how to build a component with Gulp. At this time, I have a Vue component that looks like this:

**my-component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {};
    },

    props: {
      message: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },

    methods: {
      display: function() {
        alert(this.message);
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

I'm building this component via Gulp. My gulpfile.js has the following:

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const vueify = require('gulp-vueify2');

gulp.task('default', ['build']);

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/my-component.vue')
        .pipe(vueify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy'))
    ;
});
```

When I run this, I have my-component.js in the "deploy" directory. When I view that file, I see the following at the top of my-component.js

`var __vueify_style_dispose__ = require("vueify/lib/insert-css")`

I'm trying to load the component in an HTML file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./my-component.js"></script>
```

The script loads. However, there is an error in the console that says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How do I build the component such that `require` is not used? Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. You can avoid this error by extracting the css with gulp-vueify2 extractCSS option. But I don't think you can't make the generated component work without shimming require() (or by executing it in an env that does support modules...). I apology for that; it was probably a quite bad suggestion. I'll try to find a reasonable workaround, but I'm not too optimistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I did find something without the need of any require module.
That's a bit ugly so you may not like it.

**Step 1:**
Extract CSS in `gulpfile.js`.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const vueify = require('gulp-vueify2');

gulp.task('default', ['build']);

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/my-component.vue')
        .pipe(vueify({
            extractCSS: true,
            CSSOut: './deploy/bundle.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./deploy'))
    ;
});
```

**Step 2:** Your component, `my-component.vue`.

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">
      World
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
      data() {
          return {};
      },

      props: {
          message: {
              type: String,
              default: ''
          }
      }
  };
  // Well, hu, you have no module so just keep your component somewhere.
  window.vueComponents['my-component'] = module.exports;
</script>

<style>
    .foo {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**Step 3:** The `index.html`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bundle.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.module = {}; // Yeah just avoid the error as you have no module
            window.vueComponents = {}; // Global register of your components...
        </script>
        <script src="./my-component.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div>
                {{ foo }}
                <my-component></my-component>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            new Vue({
                // Here you give your component to your vue instance
                components: window.vueComponents, 
                data() {
                    return {
                        foo: 'Hello'
                    };
                },
                el: '#app'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But definitely, try a js bundle.