# Precompile vue template into render functions

Tags: webpack, vue.js, browserify

I am writing one single page of my website in Vue.js. I have a `file.html` and a `file.js`. `file.html` looks like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script> 
<body>
   <div id="app"> 
    // everything to be displayed on the page (data, v-if & v-else tags etc.)
   </div>
</body>
```

while `file.js` looks like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        msg: "hello",
        // some other data
    }
});
```

When I load the website, a warning shows:

> vue@2.3.4:440 [Vue warn]: It seems you are using the standalone build
>   of Vue.js in an environment with Content Security Policy that
>   prohibits unsafe-eval. The template compiler cannot work in this
>   environment. Consider relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or
>   pre-compiling your templates into render functions.

I have to disallow eval in my application, so the only way is to precompile the vue codes. I have looked up on Webpack and Browserify, but they seems quite complex and always used with one whole application, while I just want to precompile one single file.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that as far as I know.
To pre-compile templates you must use single files components (or jsx).

Here is I think a comprehensive list of your alternatives:

- Use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) with [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify).
- Use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with [vue loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader).
- Use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-vueify2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vueify2) (my package). It allows you to
  compile a single file without bundling the whole thing (but like the
  previous solutions, it must be a single file component), but it's quite tricky 
  to get to work in environment that does not support a native module
  system, such as most browsers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521672/gulp-compiling-vue-component-without-require/44523010#44523010)).
- Use the [jsx module for babel](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx).
- Maybe you can imagine a custom solution using [the core template compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler).